# skipping if{} even though the condition is true?

Tags: autohotkey

I have no idea what went wrong, but if statement is skipping its statement even though the condition is clearly true. I checked with MsgBox or ToolTip right before the if statement to check that toughEnemy does equal to false. You can see the log, and the code skips from line 55 to 60.. I know that there is a flow in my code not ahk, but I can't find it.
Any help? thanks.

```
Gosub, CheckEnemyBlackList

if (tughEnemy = false) {
MsgBox, %toughEnemy%
    mouseX := 575
    break ; this statement is in a loop.
}

CheckEnemyBlackList:
Loop, read, EnemyBlackList.txt
{
    if (A_LoopReadLine = enemyID) {
    toughEnemy = true
    }
    else {
    toughEnemy = false
    }
}
return

below are the log
166: Loop,read,EnemyBlackList.txt
168: if (A_LoopReadLine = enemyID)  
172: toughEnemy = false
173: }
174: MsgBox,%A_LoopReadLine% %toughEnemy% (0.75)
175: }
176: Return
055: if (toughEnemy = false)  
060: }
```

Comment: Third line says `if (tughEnemy = false) {`. Could that be the problem?

Comment: @MCL ah thanks for going it through carefully, but that is copying error. the original script is okay..

Comment: please post the original script then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try changing these lines:

```
toughEnemy = true
toughEnemy = false
```

to this:

```
toughEnemy := true
toughEnemy := false
```

reference:

- Autohotkey Help > Basic Usage and Syntax > Variables and Expressions > Variables > Storing values in variables

Comment: Ah, I figured this out, and forgot to put it here myself. But thanks a lot! This expression and variable things drives me mad, I had to read the help section like 10 times.. :/